# I have problem to distribute my app to App Store, "Code Signing "Vuforia.framework" failed."

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia, xcode10.2

I need help. I make an AR app for iOS using Unity 2019.2.0f1 and Vuforia 8.3.9. I don't have a problem when build or archive it. But when I want to distribute it failed with error "code signing "Vuforia.framework" failed.".

For a few days I try to google this issue and try few workarounds like try to edit build version Vuforia.framework info.plist and move the Vuforia.framework from the 'Link Binary With Libraries into 'Copy Bundle Resources' and nothing work.

It works fine with Xcode 9 when I change the Vuforia.framework info.plist build version but not working with the Xcode 10.2.1. I can use xcode 9 but we cannot publish the app anymore with Xcode below 10.1 anymore. Thanks in advance.